# How to Count on a specific column using CountAsync EF Core

Tags: sql-server, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

On MSDN https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-6.0#add-paging-to-students-index they use
`_context.DBSet.CountAsync()` to count the number of rows on the table. This query is translated to `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DBSET` . How can I count on a specific column?
For example `SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM DBSET`.

Comment: did you manage in the end?  I need the same for performance reasons

Comment: @Learner I did not find anything. I did some optimizations on the rest of my queries though and I no longer had performance issues. So maybe look into optimizing the rest of your code

Answer (score 0):

If you select count from whole recordset, you can apply filer with check to `null`, it is equivalent to `Count(expr)` SQL

```cs
var cnt = await _context.DBSet.CountAsync(x => x.ID != null);
```

With grouping it is possible to reproduce `Count(expr)` generation

```cs
var query = _context.DBSet.GroupBy(x => x.Some)
   .Select(g => new 
    {
        g.Key,
        Count = g.Select(s => s.ID).Count()
    });
```

Or with grouping by constant

```cs
var query = _context.DBSet.GroupBy(x => 1)
   .Select(g => g.Select(s => s.ID).Count()); 

var cnt = await query.FirstAsync();
```

Comment: For the first suggestion ef core translates it to the same query as simple CountAsync(). The next two suggestions still translate to COUNT(*) and just group by ID. I don't see how that is useful cause ID is unique among all elements. What i want is to create `SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM DBSet`. I mostly want to do this for performance reasons.

Comment: So use last one. You have not so much options. And also analyse Execution Plans which is better, I think both will be the same.

Comment: From the execution plans the thing that costs most is Clustered Index Scan and it seems to have the same cost on all cases. I guess i will use `context.DbSet.CountAsync()` for simplicity. I am using a really small dev server right now so maybe on a larger server I won't have performance issues. Thanks for your suggestions!